# How to identify input and output arrays of a tensoflow model for the process of ".tflite" conversion?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to generate quantized .tflite model from .pb file. For the #process I require the 'input_arrays' and 'output_arrays' of the model.

I've tried using the below methods to identify the input array and output array. But none of them worked.

## method 1:

```
import tensorflow as tf
frozen='/output/freeze/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
gf = tf.GraphDef()
gf.ParseFromString(open(frozen,'rb').read())
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ('Softmax','Placeholder')]    
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Mul')]
```

## method 2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()   
m_file = open('/output/freeze/frozen_inference_graph.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())
for n in gf.node:
    print( n.name )
```

## tflite conversion query:

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph_def_file = "new/barun/frozen_inference_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ['image_tensor']
output_arrays = ['BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/act_quant/FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars']

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays,input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,300,300,3]})
converter.inference_type = tf.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("frozen_inference_graph_fd2819_2.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

How to find the input_array and output_array of the .pb file ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the frozen model your own? In that case you can name the layers when creating the model.

Otherwise you could perhaps open the model in some sort of inspection tool, like [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), and look for the names.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the model yourself, then the `input_arrays` will be the list of names of the input placeholder tensors. The output tensor which we use for inferencing will have their names in the `output_arrays`.

If in case we have a model readily downloaded from some other source, you can have some workarounds.

1. In most TF projects, authors provide the details of the input/output tensors in the README section.
2. Also, most of the projects using the `graph.get_tensor_by_name()` method to get the input output tensors, so that they could use them for inference ( particular with `tf.Session()` ). You can explore the inference files in depth to discover the names of the tensors.

If all other methods don't work, then as mentioned by @Silfverstrom, we can use [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to visualize the graph.

Another way to visualize the graph could be [TensorBoard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard). Write the graph to an events file like,

```
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/path/to/logs', sess.graph)
```

Then open up TensorBoard like,

```
tensorboard --logdir path/to/logs
```

Finally, only graph may help you to solve the problem.